# shelve module even not creating shelf

Tags: python, storage, shelve

I am new to stackoverflow and experimenting with Python, currently just trying tutorial examples. Experienced a wonderful learning curve but got completely stuck with the following (working under windows 10):

```py
import shelve
s = shelve.open("test")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\dbm\dumb.py", line 82, in _create
    f = _io.open(self._datfile, 'r', encoding="Latin-1")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.dat'
```

It would be great to get some help to resolve this.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, by default, `shelve.open` tries to open an *existing* shelf for reading. You have to pass an explicit flag to create a *new* shelf if if doesn't already exist.

```
s = shelve.open("test", "c")
```

This is in contrast to Python 2, where the default flag *was* `"c"` instead of `"r"`.

Answer (score -1):

## How to read an error message

In general, error messages will *do their best* to tell you what's wrong. In the case of python, you'll typically start at the bottom; here

> No such file or directory: 'test.dat'

tells you exactly why the error's being thrown: test.dat doesn't exist.

Next you would read upward through the [stack trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) until we got to something that we either understood or had written recently, and we'd try to make sense of the error message from there.

## How to troubleshoot an error

- Is the stated problem *intelligible*?

  - Yes, we asked the software to do something with a (.dat?) file called "test", so we at least know what the hell the error message is *talking about*.
- Do we agree with the underlying premise of the error?

  - Specifically, does it make sense *that it should matter if `test.dat` exists or not*? [Chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58136727/10135377) covers this.
- Do we agree with the specific problem as stated?

  - For example, it wouldn't be weird at all to get such an error message when there was in fact such a file. Then we would have a *more specific question*: "Why can't the software find the file?" That's progress.
  - (Usually the answer would be either "Because it's looking in the wrong place" or "Because it doesn't have permission to access that file".)
- **Read the documentation for the tools and functions in question.**
- How can we validate either our own understanding of the situation, or the situation described in the error message?

  - Depending on the context this may involve some trial and error of re-writing our code to

    - print out (log) its state during execution
    - do something similar but different from what it was doing, which we're more certain should work.
    - do something similar but different from what it was doing, which we're more certain should **not** work.
- Ask for help.

Answer (score -1):

Seems shelve sometimes uses the dumbdbm to serialize.

Use [dbm](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html) to use dbm instead:

```
import dbm
with dbm.open($filename, 'n') as db:
  # read/write
```